# Getting the duration of audio data in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, media-player, html5-audio, web-audio-api

In a NextJS app handling audio data I have the following issue getting the length of a sound file.

Here is the relevant code. Let me know if I do something wrong or if more information is needed.

```
const AudioPlayer = ({audio=''}: {audio?: string}) => {
  const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);

  ........

  const handleLoad = () => {
        console.log('-handleLoad(AudioPlayer)- CALLED !!!')
    console.log('duration -> '+audioRef.current!.duration.toString())
    setDuration(audioRef.current!.duration)
  }; /* End of handleLoad */

  ........


    return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <audio src={audio}
                    ref={audioRef}
                    id="audio-player"
                    onPlay={handlePlay}
                    onEnded={handleEnd}
          onLoadedMetadata={handleLoad} />
                ........
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}; /* End of AudioPlayer */

export default AudioPlayer;
```

The problem I have is that I seem to get somewhat random value for the duration.
I have seen several places on the net saying that the onLoadedMetadata event is the thing to use to catch the duration, but I get some weird results. Did I miss some details ?

Comment: Is it working on the first loading? It may be related to the SSR.

Comment: You mean that the first result I get is correct? You may be right. Why do I get several results then ? And more importantly why do I also get wrong results ?
What do you mean by SSR here ?

Comment: Normally, in SSR the players are unable to calculate dynamic data, you have to check on documentation how to handle these players on the server.

Comment: OK. SO SSR is ? Sound-System-R???

Comment: Server-side rendering, you have to restrict the component to be loaded only in the client. Check the documentation.

Comment: @SalahAdDin. I have changed my perspective and created a different post to handle this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851493/getting-audio-duration-on-the-server-and-passing-it-to-the-client.